# Cannot show apple-touch-icon in bookmarks with nuxt.js app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a website [temp-mail.io](https://temp-mail.io). And I have `apple-touch-icon.png` for Apple devices. My icon is:

- 180x180 PNG image without transparency;
- Located on root directory of website (available via `/apple-touch-icon.png`).

Some time ago I switched my website from vanilla Vue to nuxt.js for Server-Side Rendering (SSR). And now my apple-touch-icon not showing in bookmarks (only on home screen as web app).

I spent a lot of time to find errors. I'd trying to:

- Change icon location and name;
- Change icon to another image;
- Add more apple-touch-icon with `sizes` attribute;
- Add more sizes for other icons, favicons;
- Check icon via online favicon checkers (they are report me that all is good);
- Manipulate with `nuxt.config.js`: change options order, add `build.extractCSS: true` property (I'd trying to find a difference between my website and other websites using nuxt.js);
- Checked it on iPhone 8 and iPhone SE with iOS 13. And on iPad with iOS 12.

But I couldn’t get apple-touch-icon in bookmarks.
Yesterday I found website with the similar trouble:

1. https://hn-spa.nuxtjs.org (SPA version)
2. https://hn.nuxtjs.org

Both websites are similar. But #1 working as SPA. #2 working similar to my website.

And #1 **have an icon** when I'm trying to save it to the bookmarks ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVQmS.png)). #2 **haven't icon** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUngx.png)). I can't understand why.

***My question: how can I show apple-touch-icon in bookmarks?***

---

P.S. I'm always use "Clear History and Data" in settings. And always trying to repeat adding multiple times.

nuxt.js version is 2.11.0.

apple-touch-icon added to `nuxt.config.js` to `head.link`:

```
{ rel: 'apple-touch-icon', href: '/apple-touch-icon.png' }
```

Also I'm using `@nuxtjs/pwa@3.0.0-0`, but I disabled favicon property in `nuxt.config.js` to use custom favicons: `pwa.meta.favicon: false`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Masumi.
I just fixed this same error so that I will share my tips!

**1. Edit your icon path to `/static/apple-touch-icon.png`.**
(In addition, the dimensions of my file is `512 × 512px`)

**2. Edit your `nuxt.config.js` file's head code as bellow.**

```
 head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s',
    title: 'App Name',
    meta: [
      // [Things you are currently setting]
      {
        name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable',
        content: 'yes'
      },
      {
        name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style',
        content: 'black-translucent'
      },
    ],
    link: [
      // [Things you are currently setting]
      {
        rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
        type: 'image/png',
        href: 'https://www.sample.com/apple-touch-icon.png' // [your-domain]
      }
    ]
  },
```

**3. Uninstall `@nuxtjs/pwa` and remove the related codes.**
If you still cannot solve the problem, you can solve it by uninstalling the package (`npm uninstall @nuxtjs/pwa`). If you uninstall the PWA package, you need to remove the related codes such as codes in `modules`.

This answer might not fit your solution, but I'm very happy if it helps you:)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have already tried all of this and it's not helped for me

Answer (score 0):

If you can, add `www.` subdomain to your page url, not icon. I don't find any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[Masumi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959404/9155889) led me in the right direction.

I tried to use the [@nuxt/pwa](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon) package while struggling with the apple-touch-icon. Safari didn't show it. Adding this to `nuxt.config.js` solved the issue;

```js
  head: {
    ...
    link: [
      ...
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon",
        type: "image/png",
        href: "/icon.png" //If Icon is inside @/assets/ folder or available at '/...'
      }
    ]
  },
```

Be aware assets in Nuxt are by default mapped to `'/'`. So `icon.png` inside the assets folder would be [www.domain.com/icon.png](http://www.domain.com/icon.png).
If the location is somewhere else follow [Masumi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959404/9155889).

### If using [@nuxt/pwa](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/icon)

Try to disable the `meta-favicon` option as it generates it's own `apple-touch-icon` link.

```
pwa: {
  meta: {
    favicon: false
  }
}
```

Using `@nuxt/pwa` icon with the `source` option did not help me.